# ¿Cómo se debe validar con la función isset() en php 8.2?

Tags: php8, isset

estoy intentando conocer las funciones de **isset()** y **empty()** en php 8, por lo que tengo entendido, empty(), comprueba si existe la variable, entonces si la variable no existe envío los campos vacíos?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>función</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="registro.php" method="post">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email">

            <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
            <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre">

            <label for="apellido">Apellido:</label>
            <input type="text" name="apellido" id="apellido">

            <label for="password2">Contraseña:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password2">

            <input type="submit" value="Registrar">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

y aquí tengo mi php:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST)) {

    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : false;
    $nombre = isset($_POST['nombre']) ? $_POST['nombre'] : false;
    $apellido = isset($_POST['apellido']) ? $_POST['apellido'] : false;
    $password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password2'] : false;

 echo 'El nombre es: '. $nombre;

} else {
    
    echo 'error';
}
```

El verdadero detalle de todo es que si envío el formulario en blanco no se muestra del mensaje que se encuentra después del else (que dice 'error') sino que vuelve a entrar en la sentencia verdadera e imprime en blanco.

No sé si es que no entendí el uso de las funciones o algún otro detalle, gracias de antemano.

Formulario lleno:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Formulario vacío:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Son un poco parecidas pero tienen un concepto diferente, `isset()` devolverá `true` si hemos definido la variable con anterioridad y si hemos establecido su valor en algo diferente a `NULL`. Esto puede ser `0`, una cadena `vacía o false`.

Por otro lado, `empty()` devolverá true siempre que el valor de la variable se establezca en algo que se evalúe en `false` algunos ejemplos de valores son `0`, la cadena vacía `""` y la cadena `"0"`, una `matriz vacía, NULL` o false.

Revisando tu problema no entra en el apartado `else` porque no estas evaluando nada, te recomendaría evaluar los valores que pretendes que lleguen por `$_POST`, ejemplo:

```js
<?php

if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['nombre']) && isset($_POST['apellido']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

    $email = $_POST['email']);
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre']);
    $apellido = $_POST['apellido']);
    $password = $_POST['password']);

 echo 'El nombre es: '. $nombre;

} else {
    
    echo 'error';
}
?>
```

De esta manera estas evaluando cada uno de los parámetros que esperas recibir, esta condición se cumplirá si efectivamente son enviados los 4 parámetros, si envías solo uno entrara en el **else**. Para almacenar el valor de los parámetros en las variables ya no es necesario volver a comprobar con `isset`.